# Changing listview (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm-light

I wonder what the best design is to show different content dynamically in a list view.

What I want is (e.g.) depending on a radio button, a list view be filled with items (setting ItemsSource, changing column width, names and the row information itself).

What I'm currently doing is dynamically changing all the list view properties.

I wonder if it would be better to use multiple list views (maybe even as user controls), all on the same window position and hide all non-used.

Also, since I'm using MVVM Light/WPF I want to easily connect it to the XAML code if possible.

Comment: If you change Content and want the ListView to follow that change in displaying data why don't you change DataTemplate whenever you change data?

Comment: Bind ObservableCollection to your radio button and change this collection according to your actions. Check out this component https://github.com/snmslavk/WPFOnScreenKeyboard . The data of buttons changing dynamicly

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I think both might use the same solution. (why not make it an answer, so I can 'award' you the points). It looks better than hiding widgets. And the example looks very good (I now have ugly code behind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If changes in *ItemsSource* occur in time (or you want change it depending on some conditions like RadioButton's IsChecked property) you need to reflect on change your *DataTemplate*.  The way out is to create *DataTrigger* which will swap your *DataTemplates* based on some criteria.

```
   <ListView>
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding InitalSource}"/>
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource InitialDataTemplate}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AnotherSource}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AnotherDataTemplate}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
    </ListView>
```

Whenever condition of DataTrigger stops being true all changes made by *Setters* vanish, by default, therefore you do not need to add another DataTrigger in case of False value for RadioButton's IsChecked.